# RxJava ObserveOn does not properly propagate elements?

Tags: java, android, rx-java

I'm trying to do some searching when the user enters text in a TextView:

```
RxTextView.textChangeEvents(mTextView)
  .doOnNext(new Action1<CharSequence>() {
    @Override
    public void call(CharSequence charSequence) {
      System.out.println("OnNext: " + charSequence);
    }
  })
  .observeOn(mSchedulerProvider.computation())
  .delay(1, SECONDS, mSchedulerProvider.computation())
  .map(new Func1<CharSequence, Object>() {
    @Override
    public void call(CharSequence charSequence) {
      System.out.println("Map: " + charSequence);
    }
  })
  .subscribe()
```

When I execute this code on an Android device by 3 times pressing the 'a' button, I get the following result:

```
onNext: a
onNext: aa
onNext: aaa
Map: aaa
Map: aaa
Map: aaa
```

I had expected my sequence of `CharSequence` to be the same as in the `onNext` call.

When I run the following test on a JVM:

```
    mQuerySubject.onNext("a");
    mSchedulerProvider.computation().advanceTimeBy(150, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
    mQuerySubject.onNext("aa");
    mSchedulerProvider.computation().advanceTimeBy(150, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
    mQuerySubject.onNext("aaa");

    mSchedulerProvider.computation().advanceTimeBy(2, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    mSchedulerProvider.computation().triggerActions();
```

..it does print out the expected result:

```
onNext: a
onNext: aa
onNext: aaa
Map: a
Map: aa
Map: aaa
```

Why does this happen?

Comment: what purpose does delaying the observable's emits serve? I would guess that may not be the operator you are looking for. maybe a debounce that controls the time between emits would work better?

Comment: I've introduced it to simulate the query delay that would arise by mapping the text to a list of results. By doing it this way I can reproduce the issue in both android and the jvm. Irl, the delay call wouldn't be there, but the same issue occurs.

Comment: The code (after fixing the compilation error) works for me on the desktop. You could add doOnNext() inbetween the observeOn and delay and see where things disappear. (It is also remotely possible the function parameter name binds to the wrong variable if you have it in the enclosing scope as well.)

Comment: It seems like the mutable `CharSequence` gets reused by Android, causing the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `TextView`'s `TextWatcher` [seems to reuse](https://github.com/JakeWharton/RxBinding/issues/124) the (mutable) `CharSequence` for new updates, changing all the delayed items as well.

> The issue has nothing to do with RxJava. The real problem is that TextWatcher.onTextChanged invoked with the same mutable CharSequence instance, so typing a new character into EditText will make all delayed values invalid.

Thus, first mapping the `CharSequence` to a `String` solves the issue:

```
RxTextView.textChangeEvents(mTextView)
  .map(new Func1<CharSequence, String>() {
    @Override
    public void call(CharSequence charSequence) {
      return String.valueOf(charSequence);
    }
  })
  ...
```